# What info does a Mobile Browser send to the Web Server

Tags: browser

What info can be gleaned from a Mobile Phone by a website? (Not an app).

Is user specific information such as Phone Number, IMEI, Google Account info etc obtainable via HTTP headers?

Comment: Visit https://whoer.net/ from different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get very basic information on the device.

See for example the following sample requests from a Samsung Galaxy S7:

Samsung Browser:

```
Accept-Language: de-DE,de,en-US,en
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G930F Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.2 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Chrome:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G930F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Firefox:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 8.0.0; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Firefox Klar:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Focus/8.0.15 Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
x-requested-with: 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

As you can see the HTTP headers of some browsers contain the device model and the Android version number and the used browser app.

Note: Other web browsers may send additional headers.